Bertini's Theorem for a linear system with a single base point
Let $(X,H)$ be a polarised non-singular projective variety over $\mathbb C$ with $\dim X \geqslant 2$. Suppose that the base locus $\operatorname{Bs}|H| = \{p\}$ is a single point. Then Bertini's theorem implies that a general member of $|H|$ is non-singular away from $\{p\}$. Can we somehow deduce that such member must be smooth?
The reason of interest for this question is to deduce that, when $(X,-K_X)$ is a del Pezzo surface of degree 1, a general member of $|-K_X|$ is non-singular.

For the first question, it is enough to check that there is at least one divisor in your linear system which is non-singular at $p$. If yes, then the same is true for a general divisor, and since a general divisor is also smooth away from $p$, it is smooth everywhere.
For the second question --- this property (smoothness of a general anticanonical divisor at the base point $p$ on a smooth del Pezzo surface $S$ of degree 1) is well known. In fact, even the stronger property is true --- any anticanonical divisor on $S$ is smooth at $p$.

Thanks for the answer! For the first one, is it safe to say that if all divisors of $|H|$ is singular along $\operatorname{Bs}|H|$ then $\operatorname{Bs}|H|$ is necessarily non-reduced?

Right, if every divisor is singular at $p$, its local equation belongs to $\mathfrak{m}_p^2$, hence the ideal generated by these equations is also contained in $\mathfrak{m}_p^2$.
